# Fontspec error: define optical sizes (XeLaTeX)

Tags: fonts, errors, fontspec, size, optical-size

This is a cross-post to [this Thread](http://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=19769&sid=44fd6a87f1e3a3937776b589aa4ef347), as noone seemed to be able to solve the problem there. I will share solutions on both platforms.

When compiling the following MWE I receive this error:

```
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "--" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!

l.27 ... {Size = {19.91-},      Font = *-SemiboldItalicDisplay}}}]
```

I checked the code, the fontname and where the font is installed (thisMWE.tex/fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldItalicDisplay.otf).
Any suggestions? Is this a fontspec-bug?
Thank you very much in advance for help! :D

```
% !TeX program = xelatex 
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode 
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 

\setmainfont{MinionPro}[Path=fonts/serif/,Extension=.otf,Kerning=On,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},Style=Historic,Scale=1,Ligatures=Common,
UprightFeatures = { SizeFeatures = {
        {Size =     {-8.4},  Font = *-Caption},
        {Size =  {8.4-13},   Font = *},
        {Size =   {13-19.9}, Font = *-Subhead},
        {Size = {19.9-},     Font = *-Display}}},
BoldFeatures = { SizeFeatures = { 
        {Size =     {-8.4},  Font = *-SemiboldCaption},
        {Size =  {8.4-13},   Font = *-Semibold},
        {Size =   {13-19.9}, Font = *-SemiboldSubhead},
        {Size = {19.9-},     Font = *-SemiboldDisplay}}},
ItalicFeatures = { SizeFeatures = { 
        {Size =     {-8.4},  Font = *-ItalicCaption},
        {Size =  {8.4-13},   Font = *-Italic},
        {Size =   {13-19.9}, Font = *-ItalicSubhead},
        {Size = {19.9-},     Font = *-ItalicDisplay}}},
BoldItalicFeatures = { SizeFeatures = { 
        {Size =     {-8.4},  Font = *-SemiboldItalicCaption},
        {Size =  {8.4-13},   Font = *-SemiboldItalic},
        {Size =   {13-19.9}, Font = *-SemiboldItalicSubhead},
        {Size = {19.9-},     Font = *-SemiboldItalicDisplay}}}] 

\usepackage{blindtext} 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{Not relevant at all} 
\blindtext[5] 
\end{document} 
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex 
%%% TeX-engine: xetex 
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t 
%%% coding: utf-8 
%%% TeX-master: t 
%%% End:
```

Answer (score 1):

Define also the fonts (here for my Minion Pro fonts):

```
UprightFont = *-Regular,
BoldFont = *-Medium,
ItalicFont = *-It,
BoldItalicFont = *-MediumIt,
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!! That could not have been easier.